# DigitQ, LetterQ, UpperCaseQ, LowerCaseQ on empty string

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Is this a bug or I am missing something?

```
#[""] & /@ {DigitQ, LetterQ, UpperCaseQ, LowerCaseQ}
```

---

```
{True, True, True, True}
```

Comment: [Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). Also, an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50876/960227) on MathSE.

Comment: `Through[{DigitQ, LetterQ, UpperCaseQ, LowerCaseQ}[""]]` just another way :)

Comment: @AsukaMinato: `Through` is not in my vocabulary ;-)