# FromLetterNumber and "" bug or intended behaviour

Tags: string-manipulation, logic

`DigitQ` behaviour appears consistent

`""` is treated as `0` by DigitQ`

```
DigitQ[""] 
FromDigits[""]
```

> True

> 0

`" "` is not

```
DigitQ[" "] 
FromDigits[" "]
```

> False

> [image]
> FromDigits[" "]

Now for `LetterQ`

```
LetterQ[""]
LetterQ[" "]
```

> True

> False

But

```
FullForm@FromLetterNumber[0]
```

> " " (*a single space *)

This is to me implies that `" "` is a letter in contradiction with `LetterQ[" "]`.

Furthermore from `DigitQ` if we infer that `""` is `0` then `FullForm@FromLetterNumber[0]` should return `""` not `" "`.

What do you think?

Comment: Possibly related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/293233/60568

Comment: You can't really say this is a bug since it is clearly mentioned in the documentation (last bullet points under Details for `FromLetterNumber` and `LetterNumber`). It's probably implemented like this just due to convenience so that you can seamlessly convert a piece of text between its string and numeric representetation.

Comment: Perhaps the inconsistency in definitions could be considered a bug?

Comment: The documentation for `FromLetterNumber` states *`FromLetterNumber[0] gives " ".`* I think it's mentioned specifically because it's an exception; and I think the exception is included by the developers because they thought it would be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "" is treated as 0 by `DigitQ`

No, that's not what's happening. DigitQ isn't so much asserting anything as it is following rules of logic. Are there any characters in "" that are not digits? No. Then DigitQ returns True. It's similar to this:

```
AllTrue[{}, EvenQ]
(* True *)
```

The same analysis applies to `LetterQ`.

The reason `FromDigits[""]` evaluates to `0` is because `0` is the additive identity. It's just standard practice that an empty sum/product will be the additive/multiplicative identity.

As for

> This is to me implies that `" "` is a letter in contradiction with `LetterQ[" "]`.

There is no reason to assume that `FromLetterNumber` and `LetterQ` are operating under the same rules and assumptions. The use of `0` and `" "` in the `LetterNumber`/`FromLetterNumber` situation is a useful convenience, not a logical assertion.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Personally, given the overall elegance of Mathematica that Letter would imply consistency between `FromLetterNumber` and `LetterQ`.